# xslt rename tag with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i'm trying to rename a parent xml tag.
i looked it up in stackoverflow and i saw the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Response_123">
<Response>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</Response>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

unfortunately, the code is not working for my requirement.
in the sample below, the tag is associated with the namespace.

```
<ns1:Response_123 xmlns:ns1="AAA">
<System>Alpha</System>
</ns1:Response_123>
```

when i use the code above, i still get the same message (no difference in any way). How can i change the output to:

```
<ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="AAA">
<System>Alpha</System>
</ns1:Response>
```

I also tried adding namespace in the code, it did not work as well.

```
<xsl:template match="Response_123" namespace="AAA">
<Response namespace="AAA">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</Response>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add namespace in your XSLT and also call template with namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns1="AAA"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns1:Response_123">
        <Response>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```